# How to insert a JS object into an anonymous array

Tags: javascript

I have an object:

```
var JSONObject = {
    "thing": {
        "array": [{
            "a": "aaa"
        }]
    }
};
```

And I'm trying to `push` another object here:

```
var JSONObject = {
    "thing": {
        "array": [{
            "a": "aaa",
            "NEW THING": "GOES HERE"
        }]
    }
};
```

Normally, you would do:

```
JSONObject.thing.array.push({"NEW THING": "GOES HERE"})
```

But in this case I can't do that, since there's no real handle to the object; it's undefined.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do

```
JSONObject.thing.array[0]["NEW THING"] = "GOES HERE";
```

This

```
{
   "a": "aaa"
}
```

is not an array, but an object and you want to insert a new key value pair.